# jQuery Scroll with 100% height body

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am attempting to fire a jQuery function when the window scrolls using the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

However, when I set a body height of 100% (needed for formatting on the site), the scroll function does not fire. The body height is set to 100% so that the background image fills the entire browser window.

Is there any way that I can have the scroll function fired when scrolling, or an alternate function or alternate code to have a background image stretch the entire page?

Thank you

**Edit (My solution):**

This was a bit of a weird question, as it had strict conditions - ie) the body heights, and other coding I've put in whilst playing around.

However I found that I had

```
overflow:auto;
```

set on a parent div just inside the body.

The solution was to remove the overflow and add a

```
position:relative;
```

to the div surrounding all the content.

This probably won't apply to anyone else, however I thought I'd post the solution just incase!

Thanks for your help!

Cheers
Alex

Comment: is your page content greater than the viewport...in other words does your page have a scroll bar appearing anymore?

Comment: Hello - No, it does not - I have found a solution - I will edit the question with the solution!

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that it works for me when I change `overflow` to `visible` from `auto`

Answer (score 1):

You could specify background size like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url('http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and it will fill the entire browser window

Comment: then remove `height: 100%` from the body and your scroll event will be fired.